# Makefile: how to assign object to variable and iterate on object of array

Tags: linux, azure, shell, makefile

**Makefile:**

```
QUERY := "securityresources | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' | summarize by assessmentKey=name | join kind=inner ( securityresources | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments' | extend assessmentKey = extract('.*assessments/(.+?)/.*',1, id) ) on assessmentKey | where properties.additionalData.assessedResourceType == 'ContainerRegistryVulnerability' | extend status = properties.status.code | extend severity = properties.status.severity"

.ONESHELL:
check:
    # az graph query -q ${QUERY}
    results="`az graph query -q ${QUERY}`"
    @for result in $$results.data;
    do
        echo "$${result.status}"
    done
```

Output of `az graph query -q ${QUERY}` looks like:

```
{ "count": 10,
  "data" : [{"status":"healthy", "abc":"123"},
            {"status":"unhealthy", "abc":"322"},
            {"status":"healthy", "abc":"432"}
           ]
}
```

**Error:**

> /bin/bash: line 4: ${result.status}: bad substitution make: ***
>
> [Makefile:23: check] Error 1

How to assign command output to a variable and iterate on that object and access keys, values of those objects?

Comment: Dots are not supported in `sh` variable names.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question!

Comment: Still `results.data` and `result.status` are invalid `sh` variable names.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I am new to bash, how to access `data` or `status` from the variable?

Comment: Bash (or sh) will not be able to parse the JSON (string) you get back. Everything is purely text-based in this context and `result.<someting>` is meaningless (not withstanding the fact the shell variables cannot contain dots). Use `az` `--query` and  `--output tsv` (or other, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli)) to get a format that is better to parse. You could try `az ... -query data[].status --output tsv` to get list of only status values.

Comment: @Christian.K Any other way instead of using variables that I can pass the output of `az` command to `for-loop`?

Comment: @Christian.K I have some nested objects as well, consider `"abc":{"xyz":"name"}`, I was not able to fetch `"xyz"` values including `status` using `az ... -query data[].status --output tsv` Can you help in this?

Comment: Sorry, this is too much for comments. The point is, you must (and can - see link above) force az to return an output format that is easier to parse using bash and related tools. I'm afraid you'll have to read up on that. And possible the use of bash and tools as well.

Comment: There is the ubiquitous `jq` JSON stream processor: https://linuxhint.com/bash_jq_command/